# Reading a Localization.strings file from a *.ipa

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I want to retrieve a Locazable.strings taken from an *.ipa file. However when I do, I get some wierd char mix with it[image]

How can I read it?

Answer (score 22):

My friend find out how :

plutil -convert json Localizable.strings

Comment: You are my lifesaver :)

Answer (score 5):

It's in property list format.

Two methods to fix this:

- change `.strings` file to `.plist`
- find a text editor that can use auto recognition correctly.
  try `testMate` app on mac.

  [image: xcode打开]

  after:

  [image]

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Localizable", ofType: "strings", inDirectory: nil, forLocalization: "en")
let dic = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
debugPrint(dic)
```

pull your localizable.strings file in a Xcode project and run above code,
and then, you can get the dic in your Xcode console or you can store it in a text.

Comment: cool! as a developer we can process batch of string files by code!